# Button HTML Background Color

Tags: html

I'm trying to put a button on my website with a purple background, but it has gray marks around it, how do I get it?

`<button style="background-color: rgb(100, 62, 101)">Meet our games</button>`

Answer (score 1):

add border:none

```css
button{
border:none;
font-size:24px;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<button style="background-color: rgb(100, 62, 101)">Meet our games</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following thing:

```
<button style="background-color: rgb(100, 62, 101);border:none;">Meet our games</button>
```

Hope that could help you